# How can I get temporarily rid of my companion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I resumed playing *The Elder Scrolls: Online* this week, and got Isobel as a companion from the DLC *High Isle*.

Isobel doesn't like it when I steal but I've yet to finish the Thieves Guild missions, so I'd rather have her not be there when I do that.

Therefore is there any way to temporarily get rid of her for a little while and get her back afterwards (with all the stuff I gave her)?

I'm playing on PS5, if it's hidden somewhere different than on PC or XBox.

Answer (score 3):

I found out how to do it:

I needed to open the menu, then go in Collections, then in Allies, then in Companions. There Isobel was selected. Pressing the cross button (on PS5) deselected her, and coming back to the game she wasn't present anymore. My character could do all the larceny I wanted.

To get her back, I navigated to the same place in the menu, and pressed the cross button to select her. Coming back to the game she was there and greeted my character.